# Passing data from service to Component --> Child Components

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, angular-services, angular4-forms

To be very short i am using this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/aAGpiXWhnQSc7VsuvZFD?p=preview)
I have a scenario where i have to create controls dynamically by reading the elements data from a service. So when i read the data from the service its asynchronous.But i have to create some concrete objects based on the data i receive from the service and pass it to the child components. So here is my logic

Html for the Main Component is as below.

```
   <ion-content padding class="container" *ngIf="questions"> 

   <app-dynamic-form [questions]="questions"></app-dynamic-form>

   </ion-content>
```

Class for the Main Component is below

```
Class ComponentMain{

   @Input() questions: QuestionBase<any>[]=[];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,private qcs: Service)
    {
      qcs.getQuestions(this.parameter1.$key).subscribe(result => this.questions = result);
    }

}
```

Child Components Html is as follows.

```
<div *ngIf="form">
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form">

    <div *ngFor="let question of questions" class="form-row">
      <div *ngIf="question">
        <app-question [question]="question" [form]="form"></app-question>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Child Component is as follows

```
Class ChildComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @Input() questions: QuestionBase<any>[] = [];

 Constructor(){

  }

 ngAfterViewInit(){

 this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions);

 }

}
```

There is a 2nd child component which depends on childComponent to create the controls. So the controls are getting populated only in ngOnit of the 2nd child Component and due to which the controls are not getting created. I tried to use many life cycle hooks such as OnInit,OnChanges etc. But none of them actually gave me the result. I am sure i am missing something that i am unable to figure it out.

```
Class Service(){

questions: QuestionsData<any>[]=[];

getQuestions(FormKey: string) {

var dbQuestions = this.af.list('/elements', {
   query: {
   limitToLast: 200,
   orderByChild: 'formid',
   equalTo: FormKey
  }
})

  dbQuestions.subscribe(snapshots=>{
  snapshots.forEach(elementData => {
  this.questions.push(new TextboxQuestion({
        key: elementData.elementname,
        label: elementData.displaytext,
        value: elementData.elementvalue,
        required: false,
        order: elementData.sortorder
      }))
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Essentially, you would like help implementing the TODO lines here [Angular.io - Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form#questionnaire-data)?

Comment: Couple of questions for you: 1. Why did you assign Input decorator to questions in the Main Component? From what I saw, questiond in MainComponent is the component’s property, not Input from any other component. 2. You subscribe to your getQuestions() in your Service but I don’t see any declaration or return that indicates getQuestions() is a Observable? 3. What’s the error you’re getting, or expected behavior vs actual behavior?

Comment: @RichardMatsen Yes Exactly. I wiould like to exactly use that example but with a service  https://api.myjson.com/bins/o0aex with this json. So when i call the service as everything is async i have to subscribe and create an observable of questions so that the components are using it will get the data from the service..... But i am getting the undefined while creating the elements from the same example. Can you help me with the same example but with a service.  Thank you.

Comment: I managed to get it working, with about 3 or 4 tweaks. Will post shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at this example [Angular.io - Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form#questionnaire-data), it essentially builds a form from metadata at runtime.

There's a couple of comments indicating that the example isn't quite finished.

```js
@Injectable()
export class QuestionService {

  // Todo: get from a remote source of question metadata
  // Todo: make asynchronous
  getQuestions() {
  ...
```

These are the steps I took to finish it off and clean out the error messages.

### question.service.ts

Changed `getQuestions` to asynchronously return questions.

```js
Injectable()
export class QuestionService {

  constructor(
    private http: Http
  ) {}

  getQuestions$() {
    const url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/d0srd';
    return this.http.get(url)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .map(questionMetadata => this.metadataToQuestions(questionMetadata))
      .map(questions => questions.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order))
  }

  private metadataToQuestions(questionMetadata) {
    return questionMetadata.questions.map(this.toQuestion)
  }

  private toQuestion(elementData) {
    // expand for additional control types
    return new TextboxQuestion({
      key: elementData.elementname,
      label: elementData.displaytext,
      value: elementData.elementvalue,
      required: false,
      order: elementData.sortorder
    })
  }
}
```

### app.component.ts

Changed variable `questions` type to observable, added async pipe to template.

```js
@Component({
  ...
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Job Application for Heroes</h2>
      <app-dynamic-form [questions]="(questions$ | async)"></app-dynamic-form>
    </div>
  `,
  ...
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  questions$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(
    private questionService: QuestionService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.questions$ = this.questionService.getQuestions$();
  }
}
```

### dynamic-form.component.ts

Changed @Input variable `questions` to be set/get style, to handle initial null value.
Changed hook where form is created from `ngOnInit` to `ngOnChanges` to handle async arrival of questions.

```js
export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnChanges {

  private _questions = [];
  @Input() 
  set questions(value: any[]) {
    this._questions = value || [];
  }
  get questions(): any[] {
    return this._questions;
  }

  ...

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions);
  }

}
```

### dynamic-form-question.component.ts

Add additional check to `isValid` getter to ensure the control being validated exists.

```js
export class DynamicFormQuestionComponent {
  ...
  get isValid() { return this.form.controls[this.question.key] 
    ? this.form.controls[this.question.key].valid : true; }
}
```

Comment: you answered my question but one thing i have different is i have a firebase data base. So i get the data in the form of observables. So i am trying to find out how to map that observable value to the functions you explained. Thank you for the example code. Appreciate it.

Comment: You can see question.service has an http.get which returns an observable. Just substitute your firebase call there.

Comment: I did that but it is throwing error saying key not found. Once i am free i will have a look and let you know what i did to make it work.

Comment: There is no great trick to it, you just need to swap the http call for the firebase call.

Comment: I did exactly the same it says key not found.

Comment: Insufficient information, but it just sounds like a bad query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163738/discussion-between-dev-and-richard-matsen).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I have understand your problem but when I need to pass data from  service to a component I use subscription in this way.

Two component (a parent component and its children or other different component) can share a service whose interface enables bi-directional communication.

Like in the Observer pattern, in this case the scope of the service instance is the notification from a component (Publisher) and other componentents (Subscriber).

**mycomponent.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class MyComponentService{
    // Observable 
    private sampleObservable = new Subject<boolean>();
    // Observable boolean streams
    sampleSubscriber = this.sampleObservable.asObservable();
    // Event for notification from publisher to subscriber
    sampleEventChanged(value:boolean)
    {
        this.sampleObservable.next();
    }
}
```

In the component who wants to notify all subscribers a change of its state:

**mycomponent-publisher.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './mycomponent.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-control-publisher',
  template: `
  <h2>This is the publisher control</h2>
  <button (click)="announce()">Announce to subscriber</button>
  `,
  providers: [MyService]
})

export class MyControlPublisherComponent 
{
  constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

  announce() 
  {
    this.myService.sampleEventChanged(true);
  }
}
```

In the subscriber component who want to get the notification.

**mycomponent-subscriber.ts**

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './mycomponent.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-my-control-subscriber',
 template: `
 <h2>This is the subscriber control</h2>
 `,
})

export class MyControlSubscriberComponent 
{
  // Subscriptions
  private componentSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) 
  {
    // Subscription of the notifications
    this.componentSubscription= this.myService.sampleSubscriber.subscribe(value =>
    {
      // Put the code for manage the notification here
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy()
  {
    // Release subscription to avoid memory leaks when the component is destroyed
    this.componentSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

I hope that this can help you.

Comment: Richard answer my question. Thank you for your answer anyway.