# Angular 2+ subscribe not working

Tags: angular

My Profile class have property "lessonsID". I have subscribe getProfile() in my-offers.component and it succesfully returns profile. The problem is, when i click "delete" in my-announcement, that subscribed profile in my-offers.component dont changes, but when I look in my backend, where is stored that profile, that lessonID in profile is deleted. Why that subscribe not working? How to fix it?

my-offers.component.html

```
 <ul class="list">
    <li 
      class="list__item"
      *ngFor="let privateLesson of privateLessons"
    >         
      <app-my-announcement [privateLesson]="privateLesson"></app-my-announcement>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

my-offers.component.ts

```
export class MyOffersComponent implements OnInit {

myOffersId: string[];
privateLessons: PrivateLesson[] = [];

constructor(
  private _authService: AuthService,
  private _privateLessonsService: PrivateLessonsService
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this._authService.getProfile().subscribe(
    profile => {
      this.myOffersId = profile.user.lessonsID;

      this.privateLessons = [];

      this.myOffersId.filter(offerID => {
        this._privateLessonsService.getPrivateLessonByID(offerID).subscribe(
          privateLesson => {
            this.privateLessons.push(privateLesson);
          }
        );
      });
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    }                  
  );
}
```

my-announcements.components.html

```
<div class="announcement">
  <div class="announcement__data">
    <div class="data__title">
      {{ privateLesson.title }}    
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="announcement__options">
    <ul class="options">
      <li 
        class="options__item"
        (click)="onPreviewClick(privateLesson._id)"
      >
        Podgląd
      </li>
      <li 
        class="options__item"
        (click)="onDeleteClick(privateLesson._id)"
      >
        Usuń
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

my-announcements.component.ts

```
export class MyAnnouncementComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() privateLesson: PrivateLesson;
  privateLessons: PrivateLesson[];

  constructor(
   private router: Router,
   private authService: AuthService,
   private _privateLessonsService: PrivateLessonsService
 ) { }

  onDeleteClick(id: string) {
    this._privateLessonsService.deletePrivateLessonByID(id).subscribe();
    this.authService.removeLesson(id);

  }

}
```

auth.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

 getProfile() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.loadToken();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get( 'http://localhost:3000/users/profile', { headers: headers } )
        .map( res => res.json() );
  }

}
```

Comment: Your deletion subscribe doesn't do anything. `this._privateLessonsService.deletePrivateLessonByID(id).subscribe();`?

Also what should  `this.authService.removeLesson(id)` do?

Comment: I have Two data collections in DB, one whith all lesssons, another with users. This.authService.removeLesson(id) removes id from property lessonsID from actually loged user. This._privateLessonsService.deletePrivateLessonByID(id) deletes lesson from that db where arestored all lessons

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the 'Observable' on your 'AuthService' like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376442/8417618)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    // Observable 
    private removeLessonObservable = new Subject<number>();
    // Observable number streams
    removeLessonSubscriber = this.removeLessonObservable.asObservable();
    // Event for notification from publisher to subscriber
    removeLessonEvent(value:number)
    {
        this.removeLessonObservable.next();
    }

    getProfile() 
    {
        let headers = new Headers();
        this.loadToken();
        headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.get( 'http://localhost:3000/users/profile', 
            { headers: headers } ).map( res => res.json() );
    }

}
```

my-announcements.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService} from './auth.service';

export class MyAnnouncementComponent implements OnInit 
{

  @Input() privateLesson: PrivateLesson;
  privateLessons: PrivateLesson[];

  constructor(
     private router: Router,
     private authService: AuthService,
     private _privateLessonsService: PrivateLessonsService) { }

  onDeleteClick(id: string) 
  {
      this._privateLessonsService.deletePrivateLessonByID(id).subscribe();
      // Call the observable event
      this.authService.removeLessonEvent(id);    
  }
}
```

my-offers.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
    import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
    import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

    export class MyOffersComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    myOffersId: string[];
    privateLessons: PrivateLesson[] = [];

    // Subscriptions
      private authSubscription: Subscription;

    constructor(
      private _authService: AuthService,
      private _privateLessonsService: PrivateLessonsService
    ) { }



    ngOnInit() 
    {  
        // Subscription of the notifications
        this.authSubscription= this.authService.removeLessonSubscriber.subscribe(value =>
        {
            // Put the code for manage the notification here
            // 'value' contains the 'id'
            console.log(value);
        }

        this._authService.getProfile().subscribe(
            profile => {
              this.myOffersId = profile.user.lessonsID;

              this.privateLessons = [];

              this.myOffersId.filter(offerID => {
                this._privateLessonsService.getPrivateLessonByID(offerID).subscribe(
                  privateLesson => {
                    this.privateLessons.push(privateLesson);
                  }
                );
              });
            },
            err => {
              console.log(err);
              return false;
            }                  
          );
        }

    ngOnDestroy()
    {
      // Release subscription to avoid memory leaks when the component is destroyed
      this.authSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated post, please see how  AuthService loooks.

Comment: I have updated the answer according to your example.