# Angular 5, Dynamic Forms, how to change the way and form of submit?

Tags: angular, forms, express, dynamicform

i've done this example [Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) and then I extended it to work with http, I'm getting questions from database constructing a form and save anwers to user on submit, everithing else is just like in tutorial. I've just added a check if user answered question (and answer saved in his entry in mongo) when constructing form, if he did, then I add a value and id to a constructor and this input already has value checked, and its conscructor looks like this.

```
new TextboxQuestion({
    key: 'How are you?',
    label: 'How are you?',
    value: 'Good',
    required: true,
    id: fdsg6435sdgfsg34t5
  }),
```

or if a question is new to user, he doesn't have answer on his profile then consrtructor would look like this:

```
new TextboxQuestion({
    key: 'How is it going?',
    label: 'How is it going?',
    required: true,
  }),
```

What I'm struggling with is that I need to check on node for instance if question has id, than I need to update it in database and not create a new entry, but on form submit I get this:

```
{"How are you?":"Good","Are you ok?":"45","How is it going?":"ok"}
```

How do I change it to have id in it, doesn't realy matter how it will look like, I just need to not breake a form construction. Can you please help me ? :)

Comment: Couple weeks ago I asked another question, I have some code there if it will help, but all of it in angular documentation page. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539740/angular-dynamic-forms-async-does-not-work-error-error-cannot-find-control-wit

Comment: adding a key ``"id" : null`` in the object will not help ?

Comment: I'm not shure what object you mean, but I think it will help to add id property on the submit object. The question I'm trying to find answer on is how to do it :)

Comment: {"How are you?":{id:f23fdsf42453, answer: "Good"} that would work I think. or some other way. It's just that I can't figure out how to change just the payload, just the submit object, it keep interrupting with construction of a form when a page is loading.

Comment: suppose i have an object ``a = { 'name' : 'foo' , class : 'bar' }`` , i can say ``a.id = fdsfdfdf``. a will be an object with another key ``id`` .

Comment: Yes but in this example it is not that easy. I am trying to change something in question-control-service and add id field there, but it is breaking the form.